# Using 'not' in Prolog in logic statements

Tags: prolog

I'm working on a condition in Prolog but the `not` operator is not working as expected. I see `not` being used in an example here http://www.cs.trincoll.edu/~ram/cpsc352/notes/prolog/factsrules.html

I have the following statements. What i want is for `is_not_immune_to` to return the result, but `not` seems to not be working here. Without the `not` it works fine, and returns whether the Pokemon is immune.

```
weak(fire, ground).
immune(flying, ground).

is_type(charizard, fire).
is_type(charizard, flying).

is_not_immune_to(Pkmn, AtkType) :- 
    is_type(Pkmn, Type), not(immune(Type, AtkType)).
```

I get the following error when calling `is_not_immune_to` with charizard and any type..:

```
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,not/1),is_not_immune_to/0)
```

What i want is for `is_not_immune_to` to return what it should. I want to be able to use not in logic statements. How should i do that?

Comment: It looks like you call `is_not_immune_to` *without* parameters, it should be `is_not_immune_to(Pkmn, AtkType)`.

Comment: No. I am calling it like this `is_not_immune_to(charizard, ground)`

Comment: Is there a space between `is_not_immune_to` and `(charizard, ...)`?

Comment: Yes but with or without it makes no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code uses the old and deprecated `not/1` predicate, which apparently is not supported in the Prolog system you're using, hence the existence error. Use instead the standard `\+/1` predicate/prefix operator:

```
is_not_immune_to(Pkmn, AtkType) :- 
    is_type(Pkmn, Type), \+ immune(Type, AtkType).
```

With this change, you get for your sample call:

```
| ?- is_not_immune_to(charizard, ground).

true ? ;

no
```